# How to calculate a rolling sales for n months in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I am using Microstrategy to make visualizations of my data and I need to show the rolling sales for 3,6, and 12 months. Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be an additional attribute-form on your Month-Attribute that tells you which "relative month" it really is. The downside of this is that you have to maintain the column in the database and that it's not very flexibile if you have multiple timelines (you'd had to add further "relative"-columns for that).

I.e. showing Attribute "Month" while time-base is set to 2015, June

```
Month_ID | Month_Relative
-------------------------
201508   |     2
201507   |     1
201506   |     0
201505   |    -1
201504   |    -2
201503   |    -3
```

From there you can filter your metrics on "Month_Relative BETWEEN -2 and 0" if you want the sales for past three months and so on. Possibly building a custom group, though these groups have their own (huge) limitations.

There might be other ways to achieve this, but this should be relatively easy and the benefit below.

Bit OT: After debating with support this also seems to be the way to go if you want a "actual month"-Attribute, i.e. an attribute that always opens up with the last loaded month (you simply sort by month_relative and save the report accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating 3, 6, & 12 rolling month time transformations (schema objects). These transformations can then be applied to various metrics to get you what you're after.

More complicated transformations (like these examples, or YTD) work best when they're backed by database tables. It gets complicated if your Facts are at various levels of granularity (date/month/qtr/etc). At that point, if I recall, you end up creating the transformation tables for just about every level in your date hierarchy. A single YTD transformation schema object might be backed by 3 different tables or views...day-level, month-level, and quarter-level.

If you're in a deployment where you only have permissions to create application objects but not schema objects, ask your admin for a hand.

Comment: I think the poster needs instructions on how to do this, rather than to ask someone else for help. This isn't really an answer.

Comment: Forgive the confusion. Saying it differently, if the poster is in a deployment where he only has permission to create application objects, then he couldn't create the transformations if he wanted to (and knew how). Either the admin will need to do it for him, or change his permissions.